# VueJs Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase'

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to save my posts to IndexDB and on client side to list posts even when user offline.

```
import { openDB } from 'idb'
const dbPromise = () => {
  if (!('indexedDB' in window)) {
    throw new Error('Browser does not support IndexedDB')
  }
  return openDB('OfflineDb', 1, upgradeDb => {
    if (!upgradeDb.objectStoreNames.contains('posts')) {
      upgradeDb.createObjectStore('posts')
    }
  })
}

const saveToStorage = async (storeName, datas) => {
    try {
      const db = await dbPromise()
      const tx = db.transaction(storeName, 'readwrite')
      const store = tx.objectStore(storeName)
      store.put(datas, storeName)
      return tx.complete
    } catch (error) {
      return error
    }
}

const checkStorage = async storeName => {
    try {
      const db = await dbPromise()
      const tx = db.transaction(storeName, 'readonly')
      const store = tx.objectStore(storeName)
      return store.get(storeName)
    } catch (error) {
      return error
    }
}

export default {
    checkStorage,
    saveToStorage
}
```

Here is my service. When I try to get data;

```
dbService.checkStorage('posts')
```

I'm getting error;

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': One of the specified object stores was not found.
```

Why that's happening? I found some solutions but any of them can not solve my problem

Comment: which version of `idb` are you using?

Comment: @JaromandaX 7.1.0

Comment: oh, but you seem to be using version 3 syntax - perhaps you need to [read the documentation](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb/tree/main#opendb)